# How do I resize the terminal as a proportion of the window size in Neovim?

Tags: neovim, terminal

I would like to set termwinsize to a ratio of the window size.

For example, I would like to take the current buffer height, and divide it by five, so that the terminal occupies the bottom fifth of the screen.

Should it be:

```
termwinsize = winheight / 5 * 0
```

in my `init.vim` file?

Thank you

Comment: You can access the values of options with `&option` (and assign to them with `:help :let-&`), but note the format of `termwinsize`

Comment: I read that termwinsize is blank by default but it gets its value set when you open the :term. But when I call :echo &termwinsize in the original buffer, there’s no output, but I don’t know how to call that command from within the :term buffer. I tried CTRL-W first, which also echoed nothing.